# Unable to access multiple virtual hosts under tomcat

Tags: tomcat, virtualhost

I work under tomcat, and would like to have several apps to launch under the same tomcat

In local, I called to hosts :

```
localhost
localhost_test
```

Unfortuentaly, I only can access localhost.
If I try

```
http://localhost_test
```

, it cannot find the program. How can I handle it?

My server.xml (Only the important part):

```
  <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">        
     <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm" resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
  </Realm> 

  <Host appBase="webapps" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost" unpackWARs="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>                
    <Context docBase="Mamshops.Main" path="" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Mamshops.Main"/>
  </Host>

  <Host appBase="webapps_test" autoDeploy="true" name="localhost_test" unpackWARs="true">
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs" pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"/>                
    <Context docBase="Mamshops.Test" path="" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Mamshops.Test"/>
  </Host>

</Engine>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Localhost is always assigned to 127.0.0.1 address, so you need also to assign an IP address to localhost_test, otherwise tomcat never get hit.

**Update:**

You need to edit the file `C:\WINDOWS\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on windows or `/etc/hosts` on linux to add an entry like

```
127.0.0.1 localhost_test
```

Comment: After this do I need to restart system and tomcat?

Comment: basically you don’t have to, check this https://superuser.com/questions/92634/should-i-restart-a-service-or-a-interface-to-apply-windows-hosts-configuration